# android disable onitemlongclick

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclick

I am using the following code:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

When I test the application out on my phone and hold an item down for a few seconds onItemLongClick fires.  The problem I am seeing is that my entire onItemClick does not fire and the app gets messy..atleast it does not act the same as if I do a quick touch of the item.  I tried disabling onItemLongClick in the layouts xml file but that did not help me.  I would like any longitemclicks to act as a normal onItemClick.  So either you can tap the item once and quickly or you can hold it down for a second (or few secs whatever to fire onitemlongclick) and only onItemClick runs.  Both seem to fire off when it is a longclick and I would rather have everything be executed only under onItemClick..does anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using using setClickable(true) and setLongClickable(false)

Comment: I put those two lines right before the gridView.setOnItemClickListener and it did not do anything.  Within my setOnItemClickListener lets say I delete an item or whatever.  If i do a quick touch the item deletes and refreshes.  If I do a longitemclick nothing happens..but then right after if I click the same item it will not be deleted..so it only works on quick touches and anything as in a longitemclick seems to break it

Comment: Actually it appears that if I do a longitemclick everything happens correctly besides that the gridview is not updated.  After I do a quickitemclick the grid is refreshed and the items change values/positions etc.. but if I hold the item down the grid positions move but it does not refresh itself to move the items around (if that makes any sense)?

Comment: did you return true from your onlongclick method  this will notify that longclick event is handled...?